# WiX: Error RegistryKey element contains an unexpected attribute 'ForceDeleteOnUninstall'

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I'm new to WiX. I just installed [WixW 3.7](http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/99514) in order to build an open source [JiraSVN plugin](https://github.com/Wattos/JiraSVN). But the build breaks in Visual Studio with the following errors:

```
The RegistryKey element contains an unexpected attribute 'ForceDeleteOnUninstall'.
The RegistryKey element contains an unexpected attribute 'ForceCreateOnInstall'.
```

These errors reference the  product.wxs file, which contains the following elements:

```
<Component Id="C__Registry" Guid="{40D60013-...D30D5}" Win64="yes">
<RegistryKey Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{CF732FD7-...1A7E9D}" ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes">
    <RegistryValue Value="TortoiseSVN Jira Plugin" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryKey Key="Implemented Categories">
        <RegistryKey Key="{3494FA92-...5E7831}" ForceCreateOnInstall="yes" />           </RegistryKey>
</RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

I am also getting warnings such as:

```
The 'ForceDeleteOnUninstall' attribute is not declared. 
The 'ForceCreateOnInstall' attribute is not declared.
```

From what I can find in the WiX documentation, these are standard attributes in the WiX framework. So what could be causing them to be unrecognized? Where *should* they be declared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, why are you adding those attributes? From the snippet you sent they are unnecessary and just going to bloat your install. No need to force anything there.

Second, you must have WiX v3.5 or less installed on your Visual Studio machine. Those attributes were added in WiX v3.6.

Comment: I can't speak to why the attributes are there, as I didn't add them and don't know their purpose.

Comment: ...but you were spot on as to the failure. Somehow I had followed a link to the download page of a previous version of Wix, rather than the latest (and didn't notice the discrepancy). Thanks!